# Worksheet Calculate - Font Colour Change With Cell Value Change

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching for hours but struggling to find an answer.

I have a workbook with various vlookups. I have restricted one sheet to manual calculation, and I'm trying to find a macro that will then run the calculations manually and change the font colour of changed cells.

I'm currently using `worksheet_calculate()` function but I can't work out how to make it pick out individual cell changes post-calculation and change the font colour.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which cells do you want to highlight/change color? Are those in fixed cells/Range or their position keeps changing?

Comment: You would need to read the values into an array (you will find tutorials for that), then run the calculation, and then compare the array values against the new cell values and if they changed color them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read all values into an array **before** calculation so you can compare it to the values **after** calculation:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorChangedCellsAfterCalculation()
    Dim RangeToCheck As Range 'define which range we want to check
    Set RangeToCheck = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5")

    'read values BEFORE calculation into array
    Dim PreCalcValues As Variant
    PreCalcValues = RangeToCheck.Value

    'calculate
    Application.Calculate

    'read values AFTER calculation into array
    Dim PostCalcValues As Variant
    PostCalcValues = RangeToCheck.Value

    Dim ChangedData As Range 'we collect all changed cells in this variable

    'Loop through array and check which row/column values changed
    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    For iRow = 1 To RangeToCheck.Rows.Count
        For iCol = 1 To RangeToCheck.Columns.Count
            If PreCalcValues(iRow, iCol) <> PostCalcValues(iRow, iCol) Then
                If ChangedData Is Nothing Then 'collect all changed data
                    Set ChangedData = RangeToCheck(iRow, iCol) 'first changed cell
                Else
                    Set ChangedData = Union(ChangedData, RangeToCheck(iRow, iCol)) 'add all other changed cells
                End If
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

    If Not ChangedData Is Nothing Then ChangedData.Interior.Color = vbRed 'mark all changed data red
End Sub
```

Imagine the following data …

[image]

It will turn into …

[image]

Note that if you run that on a large data, the comparison will take a lot of time. Therefore don't run this on the whole sheet but only on your desired data range.

Comment: ++ Three suggestions :) `1` Instead of hardcoding the range, you may want to use .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)? To transfer non-contiguous range to array you may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365547/non-contiguous-named-range-into-an-array-then-into-row-in-different-sheet) `2` Instead of 1 array use 2 array. One before the calculation and one after the calculation and then compare it? `3` Change the color of the range only if ChangedData is "Not Nothing" else you will get an error if the post and pre values are same :)

Comment: Thanks @PEH - this looks like it would be ideal. I'm not sure if the time to run will be a problem but I will test and see. I seem to be getting an error at the moment - Object variable or With block variable not set...any ideas?

Comment: @meg_orm In which line? I tested the code. It works if there are changes. Check my edited answer I fixed the last line (if your error was there).

Comment: @SiddharthRout to `1` Of course this could reduce load. • To `2` I actually do that? • To `3` fixed. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @PEH Yes it's that last line 'ChangedData.Interior...." I'm pretty sure I've copied the code over properly but it's still throwing up an error...?

Comment: @meg_orm meehhh, it didn't save my edit. Sorry for that. Have a look again. Last line has `If Not ChangedData Is Nothing Then` now

Comment: `2 I actually do that?` For a small dataset there will not be a significant difference but over a huge dataset, it will make a difference :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I know, I actually **have** 2 arrays `PreCalcValues` and `PostCalcValues`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use application.evaluate, evaluate your formulas and check them against the current value:

```
    Sub tst()
    For Each cl In Sheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If Application.Evaluate(cl.Formula) <> cl.Value Then
            cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
            cl.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next cl
' application.calculate or sheet calculate
    End Sub
```