# Cannot select autofiltered table data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with products I apply an autofilter and I get my filtered products

```
Set tbl = Worksheets("FOR EXPORT").ListObjects("MyTable")
'SET AUTOFILTER
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*ERROR*"
```

I want to filter the products copy them to an array to be able to export them to a CSV

So I try to select the filtered products like

```
Dim VisRng As Range
' set the new Range object to the visible cells of `tbl.Range`
Set VisRng = tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
' copy only the visible cells in range to array
tblArr = VisRng.Value
```

If I add `tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).select` it asks for an object

Even if there are about 362 filtered products I get only 196

How to copy the filtered data to variable `tblArr`? Why I get less products?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-contiguous named range into an array, then into row in different sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365547/non-contiguous-named-range-into-an-array-then-into-row-in-different-sheet) Note: Filtered data might be non-contiguous.

Comment: You mean maybe data have empty cells?

Comment: For now data start from row 2 and stops to 344 and starts againg from 349

Comment: For example if you have 10 rows and after your filer is applied there is only rows `{1, 2, 5, 6, 7}`  visible that means that the rows are not contiguous and split into to areas `{1, 2}` and `{5, 6, 7}`. Therefore you probably get into trouble when reading it into an array, the array will only contain the values of the first area. See that link above for a solution.

Comment: Another workaround could be to `VisRng.Copy` and paste the values into a new worksheet. Then export that worksheet as CSV. • Copy/Paste of a non-contiguous range makes it contiguous in the destination.

Comment: The example though is talking about a given ranges..How to adjust it to take variable ranges of non contiguous rows?

Comment: Same approach. Instead of the named range use your range `VisRng`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to `VisRng.Copy` and paste the values into a new workbook/worksheet. Then export/saving that worksheet as CSV. Copy/Paste of a non-contiguous range makes it contiguous in the destination.

Example:

```
Dim NewWB As Workbook 'create new workbook
Set NewWB = Application.Workbooks.Add

VisRng.Copy

NewWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
NewWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\MyFile.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
NewWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: @Nikos No it copies only values, but that's not an issue because CSV doesn't support formatting anyway. So even if there were formattings, saving it as CSV would strip the formattings off.

Comment: When I exported it I dont get Euro Currency If I use xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats I get US dollars

Comment: @Nikos Well, so you were talking about number formats not about formattings, that's a difference. Then use `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` to keep number formats.

Answer (score 0):

Your filtered data isn't contiguous.  If you filter your data and there are hidden rows between your firt and last filtered rows then your data isn't contiguous.

If your sort your data on `Field:=3` before filtering then you will have the contiguous range you need to put in the array.